# Comparing user input list with dictionary and printing out corresponding value

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Starting out by saying this is for school and I'm still learning so I'm not looking for a direct solution.

What I want to do is take an input from a user (one word or more).
I then make it in to a list.
I have my dictionary and the code that I'm posting is printing out the values correctly.
My question is how do I compare the characters in my list to the keys in the dictionary and then print only those values that correspond to the keys?

I have also read a ton of different questions regarding dictionaries but it was no help at all.

Example on output;

Word: wow

Output: 96669

```
user_word = input("Please enter a word: ")
user_listed = list(user_word)

def keypresses():
my_dict = {'.':1, ',':11, '?':111, '!':1111, ':':11111, 'a':2, 'b':22, 'c':222, 'd':3, 'e':33, 'f':333, 'g':4, 'h':44,
       'i':444, 'j':5, 'k':55, 'l':555, 'm':6, 'n':66, 'o':666, 'p':7, 'q':77, 'r':777, 's':7777, 't':8, 'u':88,
       'v':888, 'w':9, 'x':99, 'y':999, 'z':9999, ' ':0}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(value)
```

Comment: type `my_dict['w']` and see what comes out. That is how you access values from a dictionary. does that give you ideas on what you need to do?

Comment: Somehow replace the w with the content of my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to hand you code for the project, but I will definitely send you in a right direction;

so, 2 parts to this in my view; match each character to a key/get a value, and combine the numbers for an output.

For the first part, you can iterate character-by-character by simply making a for loop;

```
for letter in 'string':
    print(letter)
```

would output `s t r i n g`. So you can use this to find the value of the key(each letter)

Then, you can get the definition as a string(so as not to add each number mathematically) so something like;

```
letter = 'w'
value = my_dict[letter]
value_as_string = str(value)
```

then, combine this all into a for loop and add each string to each other to create the desired output.

Comment: Thank you, that will actually help me with my other exercises regarding dictionaries. Do you think I need to have it all inside a function or not? Is it common practice that a function makes it look "cleaner" ?

Comment: That's up to you! I am not sure if there is a rule of thumb regarding when to use functions and when to not, but unless you are very worried about speed it only matters which is easier for you to create and others to read if necessary.